# Integrating a Bivariate Piecewise Function

Tags: multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral

Given $$
f_{ab}(u,v)=
\begin{cases}
(1-a)u^{-a}v,\quad u^a>v^b\\
v^{1-b}, \quad\quad\quad\quad\: u^a<v^b\\
\end{cases}
$$ where the domain is on $(u,v)\in[0,1]\times[0,1].$

How would I split the integral:
$$\int_0^1\int_0^1f_{ab}(u,v)dudv.$$

?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the natural thing is 
$$
\int_0^1\int_0^1f_{ab}(u,v)~du~dv = 
\int_0^1\int_0^{v^\frac{b}{a}}f_{ab}(u,v)~du~dv + \int_0^1\int_{v^\frac{b}{a}}^1 f_{ab}(u,v)~du~dv,
$$
where the formulas used for $f_{ab}$ in the two integrals are the two "parts" of the $f$ formula in your question.

This assumes that $a,b > 0$, so that $v^{b/a}$ makes sense; in general, if it's ambiguous (e.g., $v^\frac{1}{2}$), my intended meaning is "the positive value".

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. I was thinking of first showing that either $u^a\geq v^b$ or $u^a\leq v^b$ on $[0,1]$ for all $a,b>0$, but your answer is obviously correct and simpler.